# How to make the Navigation Drawer or bottom selection bar always accessible in an android project?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sidebar

I am developing an Android project with Android Studio. 
I would like to have the menu is always accessible in every view like Google Play Store (the Sidebar) and App Store (the Bottom selection bar).

I am thinking to do it in two ways:

1. Make my app have only one activity with Navigation Drawer, all the other views are above this activity using fragments.
2. Recreate the sidebar or bottom selection bar every time I switch to another activity.

Both of these two ways are very complex and cost a lot. Do you have some better ways?

PS: If not, could you suggest me some links about how to implement these two methods?

Thanks a lot.
[image: App store bottom bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a MasterActivity that extend Activity and contain your sidebar. other Activity can extend from your MasterActivity by this way you can access your sidebar on each activity.

Comment: Thanks! Never tried this way, but I think it would work. For the bottom bar like App Store, do you have some suggestion?

Comment: I try this way in my apps,it should work for you too.for Bottom bar you can use the MasterActivity again,define bottom bar in it and use button in other activity that extend it. you can also overwrite setContentView in MasterActivity and add your view(from other activity) to part of MasterActivity view

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the default navigation drawer and default action bar.

If you are using the Android Studio then

**right click on your package** and go to **New/Activity/Navigation Drawer Activity**.

That will create navigation drawer fragment and activity automatically.
 But If you are using Eclipse then these links will be useful for you.[Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

[Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `include` tag in other layout `activity` and call `Navigation Drawer`:

```
<include
     android:id="@+id/nDrawer"
     layout="@layout/your_NavigationDrawerLayoutName"/>
```